# Mobile device htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am attempting to redirect an expired domain (keithowilliams.com) to my new domain (keithowilliams.info). I am successful in performing a htaccess 301 redirect for desktop and laptop computers, but not for mobile devices. How can make a redirect possible for mobile devices?

Here's the code I used. Thank you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^keithowilliams.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.keithowilliams.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keithowilliams.info/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules apart from these shown ones in your htaccess file?

Comment: Is this supposed to be the _real_ old domain here? Because from my location, my (desktop) browser can resolve neither `keithowilliams.com` nor `www.keithowilliams.com`, and https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3akeithowilliams.com also suggests that currently no DNS records exist.

Comment: keithowilliam.com is the old domain. When I type the old domain from my computer, I get a redirect to keithowilliams.info. The redirect is not working on my mobile phone browser. Those are the only rules that I have for a redirect. If there's a better way to do it for all devices, I welcome it.